# How to display List<BoardVo> to controller with ajax

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

Can I ask you a question?

[image: 1]

If there's only one screen, insert correct but,
If i add a line like above,
title A,B
comment C,D
This is how the data is transmitted and entered.
So I'll cut it in commas
I extracted the data in an array
I don't know how to put each of them in boardvo.
I've looked for a way to put it in List, but I don't know how to write it on the controller

help me, senior..!

here is controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/board/boardWriteAction.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String boardWriteAction(Locale locale, BoardVo boardVo) throws Exception {
    
    System.out.println(boardVo.toString()); 
    
    String callbackMsg = "";
    HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
    CommonUtil commonUtil = new CommonUtil();
    
    int resultCnt = boardService.boardInsert(boardVo);

    result.put("success", (resultCnt > 0) ? "Y" : "N");
    callbackMsg = commonUtil.getJsonCallBackString(" ", result);
    
    System.out.println("callbackMsg::" + callbackMsg);

    return callbackMsg;
}
```

here is BoardVo

```
public class BoardVo {

private String  boardType;
private int     boardNum;
private String  boardTitle;
private String  boardComment;
private String  creator;
private String  modifier;
private int totalCnt;

private List<BoardVo> BoardVoList;

public List<BoardVo> getBoardVoList() {
    return BoardVoList;
}
public void setBoardVoList(List<BoardVo> boardVoList) {
    this.BoardVoList = boardVoList;
}
```

here is boardServiceImpl

```
@Override
public int boardInsert(BoardVo boardVo) throws Exception {
    int resultCnt=0;
    
    // title value 111, 222, 333 
    String title = boardVo.getBoardTitle();
    // comment value 111, 222, 333 
    String comment = boardVo.getBoardComment();
    
    // title , 
    if (title.contains(",")) {
        // split ,
        String[] arrayTitle = title.split(",");
        String[] arrayComment = comment.split(",");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayTitle.length; i++) {
            BoardVo newBoardVo = new BoardVo();
            newBoardVo.setBoardTitle(arrayTitle[i]);
            newBoardVo.setBoardComment(arrayComment[i]);
            
            resultCnt += boardDao.boardInsert(newBoardVo);
        }
    } else {
        resultCnt += boardDao.boardInsert(boardVo);
    }
    
    return resultCnt++;
}
```

here is boardWrite / ajax

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j("#submit").on("click",function(){
        var $frm = $j('.boardWrite :input');
        var param = $frm.serialize();
        
        alert(param);
        
        $j.ajax({
            url : "/board/boardWriteAction.do",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data : param, //JSON.stringify(param),
            traditional: true,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                alert("writeSuccess");
                
                alert("message:" + data.success);
                
                location.href = "/board/boardList.do?pageNo=1";
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert("failed");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please let us know why you have `private List<BoardVo> BoardVoList;
` within same `BoardVo` class?, You might need to have another class which might hold list of `BoardVo`

Comment: Simple solution for your problem is move your `private List<BoardVo> BoardVoList; ` to some other class say -- BoardCollection. Now, in your `boardWriteAction` method, you can add each input `BoardVo` to this list which you can able to return back. Currently not sure what your `callbackMsg = commonUtil.getJsonCallBackString(" ", result);` call is doing, but seems you are doing some sort of hashmap to json conversion here. So please check if returning List is compatible with this or not.